# Run the same function for all selects elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that looks like this Table:

[image: Table]

For each select (when changed) I want to run a function that uses the values from that specific row

I have this but only works for the first select

```
$('#selectID').change(function(){
    var tr =$(this).closest('tr');
    var IDD = tr.find($('#selectID option:selected')).val();
);
```

Comment: Not related, but you have a missing `}` before the final `);`. Is this how your code looks?

Comment: IDs have to be unique so there can always only be one element with the id `selectID`. And the query will stop after the first element with the given I was found.

Answer (score 1):

Target all your selects, then use an instance of `this` to access the value:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

id of button duplicate so it is not working 
**best way** set button class="selectID"
then write this code

```
$('.selectID').change(function(){
var tr =$(this).closest('tr');
var IDD = tr.find($('#selectID option:selected')).val();
 );
```

Comment: <button class="selectID">submit</button>